# writing to a text file

Tags: c#, string

I need to write some html tags into a txt file that has javascript in it as well. Can I just replace the html tag after creating the fresh tag? (if yes, how do I replace existing or old tag with new tag.). Or just recreate the whole content within that text file.

I am using VS 2010, c#, it's a console app that I will have scheduler run 5am everyday.

So, I have 2 tags (parent div and child div). Basically I need to replace the child div. Here is the link of the txt file. I am talking about child div "slide" . This is what I need to recreate every day.

```
<div class="slides_container">
   <div class="slide">
    <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/jliba/4665625073/" title="145.365 - Happy Bokeh Thursday! | Flickr - Photo Sharing!" target="_blank"><img src="img/slide-1.jpg" width="570" height="270" alt="Slide 1"></a>
     <div class="caption" style="bottom:0">
        <p>Happy Bokeh Thursday!</p>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="slide">
    <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/stephangeyer/3020487807/" title="Taxi | Flickr - Photo Sharing!" target="_blank"><img src="img/slide-2.jpg" width="570" height="270" alt="Slide 2"></a>
     <div class="caption">
       <p>Taxi</p>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks
Mike

Comment: Could you show examples of how does this file looks like before and after the replace?

Comment: More details please. How do you find the original tags, what is the structure of the file you wish to write to?

Comment: Have you tried `mind-readers.com` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you using a HTML Parser to manipulate HTML. [Html Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) is great for this job.

Comment: Actually, I am not allowed to download or install plug-ins.

Comment: @Mike Ozark, is the HTML you are trying to manipulate a valid XHTML file? If yes you could use standard XML manipulation classes built-in .NET such as XDocument or XmlReader/XmlWriter for example. It will be harder but feasible. If it not valid XHTML then things might get really ugly if you are not allowed to use third party components.

Comment: Thanks for your input. That's what I was looking for (some guidance). I will then wipe out the content and re-write the text file (which will have javascript and new html tags). I think this is easier. Thanks Darin.